# Linking S3 bucket to DynamoDB using AWS Lambda

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

Currently struggling to link my S3 bucket to my DynamoDB using the AWS Lambda function in Python 2.7.

Completely new to AWS so any help is appreciated. I've looked at various online tutorials but none of them seem to work, the file format I want to print from the S3 to the DB is a CSV file.

Expected results would be for the records in my CSV file to be displayed in my DynamoDB once a CSV file is added to the S3 bucket and the Lambda is triggered.

Comment: trigger a lambda function whenever new file is uploaded, load the file in memory and insert the data in dynamodb one by one or using batch operation. Take care of the cases where file is too large.

Answer (score 0):

The flow that you are trying to achieve is this:
1. An object created in S3, will invoke a Lambda. This you can configure in S3.
2. Lambda will read the file from S3, and then write to DynamoDB. So Lambda needs permissions to read from S3, and write to DynamoDB.

In Lambda there is something called "Execution Role". This is where you need to create/associate a Role, which will have the required IAM permissions to read from S3 bucket, and write to DynamoDB.